# How to logout all others devices like Facebook's "End All Activity"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

A function that logout all other devices of the same user. I need it behaves like Devise logout after changing password.
Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried, and it what ways your attempts haven't worked.

Comment: I tried using Desive forget_me! but it's not what I want.
I want the function behave like when after changed password, the site (logged in by another browser) automatically sign user out.

Comment: I tried my luck with "session[:user_id] = nil" too, but it came nowhere.

Comment: did you reach an answer in the end? I need the same thing